# Get contents from 2 urls by file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

How can I get contents from 2 urls by `file_get_contents();` at the same time?

```
$url1 ="https://site1.com";
$url2 ="https://site2.com";

$urls = file_get_contents($url1 + $url2);
echo $urls;
```

Comment: I don't think you know how URL's work. Gluing the addresses together wil just create a new, invalid, address. Try calling `file_get_contents` twice, or check the documentation to see if there is a way to call it with a list of URLs,

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but you can get the first and then the second and append the contents to the first:

```
$urls = file_get_contents($url1) . file_get_contents($url2);
```

Or:

```
$urls  = file_get_contents($url1);
$urls .= file_get_contents($url2);
```

If you have many URLs then create an array and loop them:

```
$urls = ["https://site1.com", "https://site2.com"];
$result = '';

foreach($urls as $url) {
   $result .= file_get_contents($url);
}
```